# How To Send meassage from react app to extension and get response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I developed an external site in React, which should be related to my Google extension I saw all kinds of solutions like : chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal , but chrome.runtime.sendmessage is not working from my react app so how should I do it ?

Comment: Did you look at this yet? https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#host-page-communication

Comment: Yes but this solution didn`t work for me, it work only without port and the post message send the message to every body that listen , and one time it's work and second no

Comment: Sending to a React app is a problem in general because its script is contained. What you can do is put something like `window.receive = message => { ... }` in your React's onmount, then have your extension insert a script into the DOM that calls the function. As an aside, you should put more details and relevant code in your question, otherwise it's going to get flagged soon.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.